# How do I fix the color shift on the text?

Tags: 20.04, text

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 so I'm still very new to Ubuntu. I like it and have gotten a few things done already like overclocking my monitor and customizing everything.

Though, there's this 1 small little thing that bothers me. All of the text has a color shift. There's blue on the left and red on the right. I've included a picture of it below. I had a similar issue with this in Windows but was able to sort-of fix it with the TrueType or ClearType, can't quite remember the name of the app. Any ideas is appreciated, thanks in advance!

[This picture is small, you have to zoom in.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AK6Y.png)

Comment: Is your monitor a CRT or LCD type?

Comment: You should also edit your question and include the detail @heynnema is requesting in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start GNOME `Tweaks`. Adjust these settings...

[image]

If you've got a CRT type video monitor, it may need convergence, to properly align the RGB color beams.

Pattern used to align example...

[image]

Misaligned example...

[image]

Comment: I put it on Standard antialiasing and after a restart that fixed it. Thanks!